# Markdown syntax for syntax highlighting in README.md on Github

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

I'm experiencing a small problem writing a README.md for a project on http://github.com, apparently I'm not able to syntax highlight my code.
This is the first time I write a README.md on Github (although I have some experience with markdown on other platforms) so my problem can be a very stupid mistake by my side.

Using http://github-preview.herokuapp.com/ and entering some simple markup taken directly from Github docs:

````
```ruby
require 'redcarpet'
markdown = Redcarpet.new("Hello World!")
puts markdown.to_html
```
````

I don't see syntax highlighting...

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for you your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would see the right syntax highlighting if you edit a `README.md` directly in your GitHub repo.

But the [kei-s/github-preview](https://github.com/kei-s/github-preview) project doesn't support all the features of [GitHub Flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/).

Answer (score 0):

If you edited a README.md file directly in your GitHub repository, you would see the appropriate syntax highlighting. https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/